# Postgresql.conf not found

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I was trying to install postgresql by this tutorial http://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html to use the tool for bd Powa.

I am use S.O. debian 8 Jessie.

I ran:

```
 apt-get install postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6
 apt-get install postgresql-9.6-powa
```

So far so good, the DBMS has gone up and I can create tables etc.

But I'm not finding where the postgresql.conf file is.
I tried searching using locate postgresql.conf, but can not find, I suspect it was not created.
I need to add some libraries in the parameter: shared_preload_libraries

Has anyone installed postgresql in this way, and could it tell you where the postgresql.conf file might be, or another one to configure the shared_preload_libraries parameter?

Comment: `find /etc/postgresql -type f 2>/dev/null | grep conf`

Comment: Apparently there is a tool in Debian to show you where the data directory is: [pg_lsclusters](https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#Listing_existing_database_clusters)

Comment: `ps -aux | grep -i 'postgres.*config'` also could to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to know under which settings PostgreSQL is currently running, one good way to do it is to have a look at the [pg_settings view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html):

```
SELECT name, setting, context
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name LIKE '%conf%';
```

I've added the context column to know how new values will be taken into account (a server restart, a config reload, ...).

You could also use the [SHOW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-show.html) command:

```
SHOW config_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your OS is, you always can use the `psql` utility, DBeaver or any other client tool, to type the SQL `show` command to see the value of any run-time setting.

For example, on my BigSur OSX system, where I have installed PostgreSQL v13 with the EDB installer, these are the locations for `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files using `psql` utility, sudden as the `postgres` user:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'show config_file'
Password for user postgres: 
                 config_file                 
---------------------------------------------
 /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

```
psql -U postgres -c 'show hba_file'
Password for user postgres: 
                hba_file                 
-----------------------------------------
 /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```